# javascript 2 url from 1 button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, zend-framework

Im working with Zend_Framework, and i need a little help.

I got this in my controller :

```
$link= new Zend_Form_Element_Button(
            'lien_consigne',
            array(
                    'label' => 'link',
                    'onClick' => 'gestion_lien_consigne()',

            )
    );
    $this->addElement($link);
```

I would like my button redirect on 1 choosen link to the value of an other value named id_profil.

My javascript function :

```
function gestion_lien_consigne()
{
    var value = $("select#profil_id").val();
    if(value  == "1")
        document.getElementById("lien_consigne").onClick="javascript:window.open('http://google.com)";
    else
        document.getElementById("lien_consigne").onClick="javascript:window.open('http://yahoo.com)";
}
```

Right now, the button is displayed on my site, but when i click on this, nothing happens.  Have u an idea why this is not working?

PS: I hope you can understand my English, i'm really sorry for this.

Comment: C in `onclick` need to be in lowe case. `document.getElementById("lien_consigne").onclick` also you have error, you didn't close single quote in urls.

Comment: Yeah i saw this. I just saw the answer of vijay and it's perfect ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply open the required URL in `window.open`. In your code you are trying to change the `onclick` attribute of the button which will not have any visual effect. So modify your function like  below:

```
function gestion_lien_consigne()
{
    var value = $("select#profil_id").val();
    if(value  == "1")
        window.open('http://google.com');
    else
      window.open('http://yahoo.com');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's exactly what i wanted to do ! :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  function gestion_lien_consigne() {
    var value = $("select#profil_id").val();
    if (value == "1") {
        $("#lien_consigne").on('click', function() {
            window.open('http://google.com');
        });
    } else {
        $("#lien_consigne").on('click', function() {
            window.open('http://yahoo.com');
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, i put this on the javascript function ? 
Im sorry i dont really get it ^^

Comment: Thx ! It's working too ! 
But what's the difference with the Vijay's solution ?
One is better or it is equivalent?

Comment: My version has a listener to the  `lien_consigne` element. Whenever you click it, it triggers the window to open.
I am not sure what exactly did you want

Comment: I try to test ur fonction and i dont know why, if several times on it (only 1 per 1) it will open many page. 
Atleast, thanks for ur answers, i will check on internet the interest of listener.